# Using Excel VBA on PeopleSoft hyperlink and pop-up message

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink, excel-2010, peoplesoft

My macro loops through and clicks on a list of hyperlinks.  However, each time a link is clicked, a pop-up message is displayed with 3 options: (1) Open, (2) Save, and (3) Save as.

Is it possible with Excel VBA to click on the "Save As" option?  Currently, users have to click on each pop-up (over 200 times).  I would definitely like to automate this if it is possible.

Thanks for your help in advance.........

Comment: Please edit your question and include the relevant source HTML from the page.

Comment: @TimWilliams..........I'm unable to see the HTML for the pop-up message

Comment: I meant for the click-on links, not for the pop-up.

Comment: Can you please post your Excel Macro?  It sounds to me like you don't want to "click" the link but you want to get the URL and download the file at that location.

Comment: @Darryls99.........I'm currently using the following lines to open each report:                                                                                                      Cells(r, 1).Select
Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True  What happens next is that I get a pop-up to either (1) Open, (2) Save, and (3) Save as.  I want to select the "Open" option.  Then the code saves the open report to the location that I want.  It works pretty good except the user has to click "open" over 200 times to the reports in the correct location.

Comment: @Darryls99.........I would like to automate it so they never have to click "open".  It's not the best solution and is definitely better than what they are doing now......